# NavigationDrawer onItemClick is not fired

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, navigation-drawer

Inside of FragmentActivity I'm trying to use NavigationDrawer with ArrayAdapter.
It all seems to work finde despite the fact that onItemClick is never fired (after clicking anywhere the drawer simply closes).

I've read almost infinite number of threads with the similar problem, usually solved by adding:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

To all the items like buttons etc. I tried adding that to literally everything. I also tried adding

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

to my parent layout. In order to ensure focus on DrawerLayout I called:

`hashTagDrawerLayout.requestFocus();`

inside onDrawerOpened. As you can guess... nothing worked so far, so I suspect the reason might not be in focus.

Initialization of my drawer inside of activity:

```
private ArrayList<String> hashTagValues; //values into list are loaded before  initializeHashTagNavigationDrower is called
private void initializeHashTagNavigationDrower() {
    hashTagDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    hashTagListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    hashTagListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.hashtag_list_item, R.id.textView1, hashTagValues
                    .toArray(new String[hashTagValues.size()])));
    hashTagListView.setOnItemClickListener(new NavigationDrawerListener(
            hashTagListView));// to nie działa :/
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    hashTagDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    hashTagDrawerLayout, R.drawable.icon, R.string.open_drawer,
            R.string.close_drawer) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
```

My main.xml is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
        android:name="com.example.SelectionFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="com.example.SplashFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userSettingsFragment"
        android:name="com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my hashtag_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my action bar layout:
action_bar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/add_photo"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_photo"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/take_photo">
</item>
```

As you cans see I'm using facebook widget - is it possible that focus is being 'stolen' by something in facebook fragment, despite the fact that it is not even visible?
I'll appriciate any tips on how to get it working.

Comment: why do you have fragments also in the xml.? I guess you are confused. Also where do you populate `hashTagValues`

Comment: So that I can find them using my FragmentManager. I am learning based on Facebook samples for android and this is how they handle it in Scrumptious app. Is that not a correct solution?

Comment: no you have a framelayout. that is your container. You add fragments to the container

Comment: Now I'm confused. I can remove redundant LinearLayout and fragments will be directly under FrameLayout, but I can't see how can I not put them into xml at all...

Comment: pls read this before coding http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: I read it again and still nothing :(. Maybe I'll just add this: I don't want NavigationDrawer to mess up with my fragments - I want it to call totally independent actions.

Answer (score 0):

I had two classes:

```
OnDrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
```

and

```
DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

I had only 2 list items in drawer, so I specified anonymous View.OnClickListener in DrawerAdapter for each of both items. Then, after few days not working on this code I was refactoring something and implemented onClick functionality also in OnDrawerItemClickListener (which was previously empty). This was not working and as you mentioned above, I also googled out and tried a lot of solutions but none of them was working. Then I reviewed the code and found that anonymous listeners in DrawerAdapter, removed them and everything was working just fine.